# Is there a way to use the LIKE operator from an entity framework query?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, sql-like

OK, I want to use the LIKE keyword from an Entity Framework query for a rather unorthodox reason - I want to match strings *more precisely* than when using the equals operator.

Because the equals operator [automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854769/linq-automatically-trims-my-string) [pads](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626) the string to be matched with spaces such that `col = 'foo '` will actually return a row where `col` equals `'foo'` OR `'foo '`, I want to force trailing whitespaces to be taken into account, and the LIKE operator actually does that.

I know that you can coerce Entity Framework into using the LIKE operator using `.StartsWith`, `.EndsWith`, and `.Contains` in a query.  However, as might be expected, this causes EF to prefix, suffix, and surround the queried text with wildcard `%` characters.  Is there a way I can actually get Entity Framework to directly use the LIKE operator in SQL to match a string in a query of mine, without adding wildcard characters?  Ideally it would look like this:

```
string usernameToMatch = "admin ";
if (context.Users.Where(usr => usr.Username.Like(usernameToMatch)).Any()) {
    // An account with username 'admin ' ACTUALLY exists
}
else {
    // An account with username 'admin' may exist, but 'admin ' doesn't
}
```

I can't find a way to do this directly; right now, the best I can think of is this hack:

```
context.Users.Where(usr =>
    usr.Username.StartsWith(usernameToMatch) &&
    usr.Username.EndsWith(usernameToMatch) &&
    usr.Username == usernameToMatch
)
```

Is there a better way?  By the way I don't want to use `PATINDEX` because it looks like a SQL Server-specific thing, not portable between databases.

Comment: "Because the equals operator automatically pads the string to be matched with spaces": I am *pretty* sure that this isn't the case.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Yes it is.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854769/linq-automatically-trims-my-string and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626

Comment: Hu, why would anyone have a behavior like this?

Comment: maybe dublicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033007/like-operator-in-entity-framework)

Comment: @JensKloster The top answer there says to use the non-standard `PATINDEX`.

Comment: @Jez yeah - but look at the buttom - Jon Skeet has a (in my opinion) a better anwser, than the one marked as accepcted.

Comment: @JensKloster Not really, he just recommends `.Contains` which I've mentioned in my question isn't acceptable.

Comment: `usr.Username.StartsWith(usernameToMatch)` would be hilariously insecure. I'd just create a user called `admin2` cause all kinds of hell. You really really shouldn't allow rough matches on authentication information.

Comment: @PhonicUK That's why I combine it with `.EndsWith` and the equality operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there doesn't seem to be a way to get EF to use the `LIKE` operator without padding it at the beginning or end with wildcard characters, as I mentioned in my question, so I ended up using this combination which, while a bit ugly, has the same effect as a `LIKE` without any wildcards:

```
context.Users.Where(usr =>
    usr.Username.StartsWith(usernameToMatch) &&
    usr.Username.EndsWith(usernameToMatch) &&
    usr.Username == usernameToMatch
)
```

So, if the value is `LIKE '[usernameToMatch]%'` and it's `LIKE '%[usernameToMatch]'` and it `= '[usernameToMatch]'` then it matches exactly.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to get EF to use `LIKE` in its query, However you could write a stored procedure that finds users using `LIKE` with an input parameter and use EF to hit your stored procedure.

Your particular situation however seems to be more of a data integrity issue though. You shouldn't be allowing users to register usernames that start or end with a space (`username.Trim()`) for pretty much this reason. Once you do that then this particular issue goes away entirely.

Also, allowing 'rough' matches on authentication details is beyond insecure. Don't do it.

Comment: Are you sure there is no way? LINQ 2 SQL had helpers for that that did translate to SQL. EF must have a mechanism for this.

Comment: There's the `SqlFunctions` methods that you can use which work for LINQ to Entities as well - but there isn't a `LIKE` method in there. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.aspx

Comment: I see that there is a way using ESQL but not LINQ to EF. LINQ support in EF is just a disgrace. L2S was much better 3 years ago.

Comment: The LINQ support is fine. C# doesn't have a 'LIKE' method (you use Regexes) and SQL doesn't support Regex's - so there isn't always a neat way of making this sit nicely in the middle. Depending on the number of users you could just use `ToList()` so that you can use any method. But for logins you should *not* be doing rough matches.

Comment: It could work just like with L2S. EF LINQ does not support all kinds of stuff (DateTime.Date anyone?).

Comment: You use `SqlFunctions.DatePart` instead.

Comment: @PhonicUK What part of "I want to match strings more precisely than when using the equals operator" don't you understand?  I do not talk in my question about using 'rough' matches anywhere - I specifically talk about using a combination of matches to achieve an *exact* match, so I think you should remove that warning at the end as it implies I talked about using rough matches.